# Facebook getLoginStatus gets status: "unknown" even when logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to ascertain whether a user is logged into Facebook using the JS SDK.
The call to FB.getLoginStatus always returns status="unknown", even when I know
I am logged into Facebook - literally, I have my Facebook home page open in the
next browser tab.

I am loading the API like this:

```
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

And in my JS code:

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
}

function statusChangeCallback( response )
{
    console.log("login status change callback: ", response);
    if (response.status === 'connected')
    {
        testAPI(); 
    }
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
    {
        // Not authorized, so show the login button
        show_block( ".loginScreen" );
    }
    else
    {
        // nothing doing
        show_block( ".loginScreen" );
    }

} // end statusChangeCallback()


window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : <my app id>,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        status     : true,
        version    : 'v12.0'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}
```

My console window shows:

```
login status change callback:  {authResponse: null, status: 'unknown'}
```

Why would I be getting a "unknown" status here? I have Facebook open in the next browser tab, so I know that I'm logged in.

Comment: Not sure if `crossorigin="anonymous"` on the script element is a good idea. No cookies will be sent with cross-domain requests then, so it might simply be due to that?

Comment: CBroe - thanks, I just got that direct from the Facebook docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).   I'll try that change though.

Comment: Drat, no change.

Comment: This still a problem - whether logged in to Facebook or not, the call to getLoginStatus always returns "unknown". I have tried multiple parameter sets to BFB.init (cookie, xfbml, status), and loaded the API with and without the 'crossorigin="anonymous"' setting. No change. Any thoughts?